# Deploy havana to two nodes

Tags: juju, openstack

Hello what should i do to deploy openstack havana to two nodes... I have tryed everything but get only error 500 when i try to get to the dashboard. I use - quantum,cinder,glance,nova-compute-nova-cloud-controller, keystone,openstack-dashboard,mysql,rabbitmq-server ... i deploy --to 0 --> juju-gui and --to 1 openstack-dashboard. I put in nova-cloud-controller -->Quantum and as openstack-origin - cloud:precise-havana . Is there everything else ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to deploy *any* OpenStack release on only two nodes, and even if it is possible, it will require a dense containerized deployment, including networking between these containers. The latter is not yet supported by juju-core, but it is being worked on at the moment.